# Where can I find DeskUtil documentation?

Tags: delphi, opentools

Where I can find DeskUtil documentation/help? I am trying to build Delphi add-in and I have some troubles with saving/registering/loading the add-in docking form into the active IDE desktop. I am using the DeskUtil methods after reading some examples here and there, but, examples don’t go deep in how these methods work, and in the mechanism of the IDE loading/destroying. Is there any official documentation/help about the DeskUtil or the OpenTools Api? In other words, how and where can developer like me get deep knowledge (not articles or demos) about IDE and OpenTools Api?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

You can have a look at the [GExperts "Erik's Open Tools API FAQ"](http://www.gexperts.org/otafaq.html) and also search for examples in the [GExperts](http://www.gexperts.org/) code.

Comment: Thanks François, this is very good for start, I've seen it before, but when building add-in for different versions of Delphi, say from D6 to D2010 you will notice different behaviors between these versions IDE, because of this I asked for an (official) documentation (where these changes may be documented). Is there such documentation?

Answer (score 3):

Also see articles by Allen Bauer:

[Opening Doors: Notes On the Delphi ToolsAPI by its Creator](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/20360)

[Opening Doors: Notes On the Delphi ToolsAPI by its Creator - Part 2](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/20419)

[Opening Doors: Getting Inside the IDE](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/21114)

[Units and Forms required to create Dockable IDE Forms](http://cc.embarcadero.com/item/14529)